# How to remove repeated data and sum its value on sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

Lets say I have a database table named "records" and it has three entities "id", "name", "score".

If there are repeated values like;

```
id  name  score
1   ben   10
2   adam   4
3   sarah  2
4   ben    5
5   mark   3
```

Since there are two ben ı can delete one of them with this sql statement

```
DELETE FROM records
WHERE id IN
( SELECT MAX(id) FROM records
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

but how can i sum the value of ben on other ben and get something like this;

```
id  name  score
1   ben    15
2   adam   4
3   sarah  2
5   mark   3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Min(id) as id ,name,SUM(score) as score FROM records
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below query :

```
select id,name,sum(score) over (partition by name) score
into #t1
from test3
order by id

DELETE FROM #t1
WHERE id IN
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM #t1
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

select * from #t1
order by id

drop table #t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
-- get min(id) and total
SELECT id = MIN(id),name, total = SUM(score)
INTO #temp
FROM records
GROUP BY name;

-- update score
UPDATE r
SET score = total
FROM records r
JOIN #temp t
  ON r.name = t.name;

-- delete redundant rows
DELETE r
FROM records r
LEFT JOIN #temp t
 ON r.id = t.id
WHERE t.id IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM records;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/MCKD90079)**</kbd>

---

Using `MERGE`:

```
MERGE records AS tgt
USING (SELECT id = MIN(id),name, total = SUM(score)
       FROM records
       GROUP BY name) AS src
 ON tgt.name = src.name
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.id <> src.id THEN
  DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET score = total;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/ZYZV23014)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ name  ║ score ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ ben   ║    15 ║
║  2 ║ adam  ║     4 ║
║  3 ║ sarah ║     2 ║
║  5 ║ mark  ║     3 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: second one with merge works well in demo however when implement it in to my code ı got this error A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;). here is my code http://dpaste.com/16DY5CN

Comment: @infoperto Use `;MERGE` Semicolon is mandatory. You should always end every statement with `;` as a good practice.

Comment: I didnt understand.Is not all one sql statement. Should I add ; before merge?,merge is the first word in all statement

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
--This will delete all duplicate records except their first occurrence. You may ignore this part if you do not need to delete
DELETE FROM T 
WHERE Id IN (
             SELECT Id FROM(
                            --This select will produce the result that you are looking for
                            SELECT Id, 
                                   name, 
                                   SUM(Score)OVER(PARTITION BY name) AS S,
                                   ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY Id ) AS RN
                            FROM T
                           ) AS K WHERE RN>1
             )
```